# Creating a Bluetooth Server with C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, sockets, bluetooth

I'm trying to create a Bluetooth Server to run on Windows in my computer. I have been reading information in several pages and following some tutorials, but I'm getting an error creating the Bluetooth sockect.

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <bthsdpdef.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>


#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <new>

using namespace std;

//Some defines
#define CXN_SUCCESS             0
#define CXN_ERROR               1



void PrintError(char* ProblemMessage, int ErrorCode);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

     WSADATA wsaData;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        printf("Ha habido un error con wsaData\n");
    }

     ULONG           ulRetCode = CXN_SUCCESS;
     LPCSADDR_INFO   lpCSAddrInfo = NULL;
     TCHAR          szThisComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
     DWORD           dwLenComputerName = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;

     SOCKET s;


     lpCSAddrInfo = (LPCSADDR_INFO) HeapAlloc( GetProcessHeap(),
                                              HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,
                                              sizeof(CSADDR_INFO) );

    if ( NULL == lpCSAddrInfo ) {
        wprintf(L"!ERROR! | Unable to allocate memory for CSADDR_INFO\n");
        ulRetCode = CXN_ERROR;
    }

    if ( CXN_SUCCESS == ulRetCode ) {

        if ( !GetComputerName(szThisComputerName, &dwLenComputerName) ) {
            wprintf(L"=CRITICAL= | GetComputerName() call failed. WSAGetLastError=[%d]\n", WSAGetLastError());
            ulRetCode = CXN_ERROR;
        }
    }

    //
    // Open a bluetooth socket using RFCOMM protocol
    //
    if ( CXN_SUCCESS == ulRetCode ) {

        //(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        s = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);

        if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            PrintError("Problem found creating the socket \n",GetLastError());
            printf("Error code: %d\n",GetLastError());

                exit(1);
        }

    }


    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();


}

void PrintError(char* ProblemMessage, int ErrorCode)
{
    const char* ConnectionString = ": ";
    char* CompleteMessage;
    LPVOID ReasonMessage;
    DWORD ReasonMessageSize;

    ReasonMessageSize = FormatMessage (FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, ErrorCode, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR) &ReasonMessage, 0, NULL);

    CompleteMessage = new(nothrow) char[lstrlen(ProblemMessage) + lstrlen(ConnectionString) + ReasonMessageSize + 1];

    if(!CompleteMessage)
        return;

    lstrcpy(CompleteMessage, ProblemMessage);
    lstrcat(CompleteMessage, ConnectionString);
    lstrcat(CompleteMessage, (char*)ReasonMessage);
    LocalFree(ReasonMessage);

    fprintf(stderr, CompleteMessage);

    delete[] CompleteMessage;

}
```

When I lauch this code, I get the error code **10047: Address family not supported by protocol family**. In the line:

```
s = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
```

What am I doing wrong? I filled the fields like it's said here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And the rest of the code is based on the sample given in:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Bluetooth-Connection-e3263296

Some other information that may be relevant, I'm using:

- Windows 7
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
- My computer do accept Bluetooth, actually I connect it to a wireless
  printer oftenly

Can anyone tell me what am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: When I try your code on my Windows 7 machine, I get what looks like a proper socket... BTW how did you determine that the error is 10047? As the socket() documentation says, you should use WSAGetLastError() instead of GetLastError() (and also notice that your second call to GetLastError() would not give you the error code you're after because by then your process has already called other Windows functions).

Comment: @Luis: `WSAGetLastError()` simply maps to `GetLastError()`. But you are right that code should call `WSAGetLastError()` in case Microsoft ever changes that implementation in the future.

Comment: @nacho22: My guess would be that you do not have a Bluetooth driver installed that is compatible with WinSock. You can use [`WSAEnumProtocols()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741574.aspx) to find out which protocols are available for use with `socket()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  True, I'd swear I once saw WSAGetLastError() as a macro but in my current VS2013, it's a prototype.

Comment: @Luis: `WSAGetLastError()` is a real exported function. But if you look at `ws2_32.dll` with a disassembler, you will see that `WSAGetLastError()` simply jumps into `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @Luis with GetLastError(), both calls give the same result, and it was 10047. I had the code with the printf in Spanish, but to upload it here I changed some things so it appear in English. Maybe I changed how was I getting the code of the error, but anyway it was 10047.